# How do I build an on grade foundation for a shed?

Tags: shed, foundation

After asking a couple of questions about what type of foundation to place an 8x10 vinyl shed, I am now ready to build an on grade foundation.  Can someone point me to detailed instructions for how to do this.  I've googled and can't find anything that goes into depth.  I'd be willing to buy a book if that's what I need to do.  My specific questions are:

how far apart should the blocks be?
how do I build the wooden frame?
how do I put the plywood on top?

update:  I found this http://www.usleisureoutdoor.com/storage-shed-platform.html

how do I attach the wood to my concrete blocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my on grade shed, I first built a bed of crushed limestone for it to rest on.  This will allow drainage and breathing room  below the shed.  I used some landscape timbers and made a "retaining wall" for the limestone just slightly larger than the footprint of the shed (like 2' around each side).  I then filled this rectangle landscape timber area with the limestone.

Then i placed 3 treated 4x4's lengthwise on top of the stone, and build the floor of the shed on top of these 4x4's.  This keeps the shed elevated 4" off the ground.

One problem we had though, was critters like raccoons and groundhogs living in that space.  To prevent this, I recently added chicken wire attached to the shed, down to the ground, and then across the ground out to the landscape timber.  I then covered this ground part with the limestone.

Comment: interesting ... whenever I've done groundhog-fencing, I've always dug down to keep them from burrowing under it.  Your way seems to be much less work.

Comment: i did push about 3 inches of the limestone back, so the wire goes down vertically from the shed, then makes a 90 degree bend and run across the ground and is attached to the landscape timber.  The i covered it back up with the limestone.

Answer (score 7):

This looks to be an excellent tutorial: http://www.finehomebuilding.com/how-to/articles/firm-foundation-backyard-shed.aspx